# Displaying image from path contained in text file

Tags: java, swing, awt, javabeans, bufferedreader

I am trying to display an image using a JFrame, but the path to that image changes about once every two seconds.  The path is contained in a text file.  I can display a single image in a JFrame without a problem, and can use a counter to display a range of different images provided I hard code the paths.  But I just do not know how to go about displaying an image that has a new path recorded in a text file every 2 seconds.

I have tried using buffer reader to read the text file then save the path to a bean but as I have the buffer reader in a loop the bean is returned null if I call it from outside the loop.

Besides this seams like a very long winded way to accomplish this task.  Could anyone suggest a simple way to achieve my goal.  I can't seam to see the wood from the trees with this.

Thanks.

BTW: This is not a homework assignment, it is simply a personal program I am making.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Consider having a thread that checks when the file was last modified. Whenever that changes, load the path and load the image. Then, update the image and request a repaint on the JFrame to update the display.

Comment: Could you give some sort of example of how this would work.  Or maybe some documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below is best for users not running Java 7+. Consider checking out MadProgrammer's solution, which would fair better for almost every application.

Might not be the best of answers, just thought it would be good to at least get one out here for this question.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * @author Obicere
 */
public class LoadImageTest {

    public LoadImageTest() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Load Image Test");
        final MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(ImageScanner.loadImage());
        final ImageScanner scanner = new ImageScanner(panel);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(scanner).start();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LoadImageTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ImageScanner implements Runnable {

        private static final File PATH_FILE = new File("image.txt");
        private final MyPanel instance;
        private long lastModified = PATH_FILE.lastModified();

        public ImageScanner(final MyPanel panel) {
            this.instance = panel;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (PATH_FILE.lastModified() != lastModified) {
                    System.out.println("Loading");
                    instance.setImage(loadImage());
                    lastModified = PATH_FILE.lastModified();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (final Exception ignored) {

                }
            }
        }

        public static Image loadImage() {
            try {
                final byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PATH_FILE.toURI()));
                final String path = new String(data);
                System.out.println(path);
                return ImageIO.read(new URL(path));
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private Image render;

        public MyPanel(final Image render) {
            this.render = render;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(render, 0, 0, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(render.getWidth(this), render.getHeight(this));
        }

        public void setImage(final Image image) {
            this.render = image;
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    repaint();
                    revalidate();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

What this does is creates a new thread to check to see if the file has been updated. This thread will run off of the EDT, so no need to worry about freezing the application. I also added a 50 ms timeout, as to not tax the CPU too much. This is up to your discretion.

What this will do is load an image and render it onto the JPanel. It's just a rough draft on how this can be done and merely stands as a concept rather than code you would actually want to use. I even feel a bit bad writing this.

Comment: I will run this code and get a full understanding of how it all works and let you know how I get on.  Thanks

Comment: I got error when I tried to run you code, I have added it to my original question

Comment: You sir are a genius, this is perfect example that I can follow and understand.

Comment: @user2352274 I rarely recommend external libraries unless it's for a corporate application, but there is a FileListener from Apache Commons. It has a fileChanged event that may work better here, than just looping. Then again, it is an external build. What I posted what just a replication in a way.

Comment: Do you have any problem with me using some of this code in my project, I don't intend for it to become commercial, not yet anyways.  Should it become commercial would you have a problem with me using it?

Comment: Not a problem at all. I am a firm believe in open-sourced code and allowing anyone to use it, so much as it doesn't harm me. Feel free to :)

Comment: Sir, you are a gentleman as well as a genius.  Something tells be it will never become commercial but just in case.

Comment: If using Java 7 you could use the new [File Watcher API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). Also consider that `lastModified` is not guaranteed to return a proper result on all systems under all conditions. You should also be calling `super.paintComponent` before painting the image, otherwise what ever was painted before the component will still remaining within the context of the `Graphics` object.  I'd also be careful updating the value that the component's `paint` method relies on from another Thread, this could lead to dirty paints...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 7, then you can take advantage of the in built File Watcher Service...

Start by taking a look at [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), in particular [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

The `SwingWorker` will allow you to monitor for changes outside of the Event Dispatching Thread, allowing your UI to continue responding to the user and system events.

The `SwingWorker` also has convenience methods for re-sync updates back to the EDT, allowing you to safely update the UI.

```
public class WatcherWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    private WatchService watcher;
    private Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
    private Path path;

    public WatcherWorker(Path path) throws IOException {
        watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.path = path;
        path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (true) {

            WatchKey key = watcher.take();
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
            if (lines.size() > 0) {
                String imagePath = lines.get(0);
                publish(imagePath);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        String imagePath = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        // load new image
        // apply image to what ever you need to use it with
        // This would assume that you have a reference to something capable of
        // using the said image ;)
    }

}
```

Then you could use something like...

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/path/to/configuration/config.txt");
WatcherWorker worker = new WatcherWorker(p1);
worker.execute();
```

Comment: Works very well. Never done anything like this before, so sorry for the sloppy answer. This is much better, +1 for sure.

Comment: @Obicere Your answer is well suited to those of use who are stuck version of Java before Java 7.  I'd simply ensure that 1- You're calling `super.paintComponent` and 2- Updating the UI from the context of the EDT ;)